# SPServices applications on SharePoint 2010. Will it work on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I'm using SPServices to develop on SharePoint 2010. My organization will be upgrading to SharePoint 2013 sometime in the future. What will I need to do (if anything) when the new SharePoint server is installed to keep using the SPServices library? Primarily I'm using GetListItems, updatelistitems, createlistitems and Query operations.

Comment: Someone, maybe you, has asked exactly the same question in March (with a stunningly similar way of phrasing and punctuation) on the [SPServices web site](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/437650) and received an answer from Marc Anderson, the author of the SPServices library. What do you think anyone else here could add?

Answer (score 0):

Per the article linked in response to your question - it does depend on a number of factors and what is deprecated between 2010 and 2013...but I *can* tell you that I was able to successfully port a company news site/portal that made extensive use of GetListItem AJAX calls and Search queries with no issues.

Keep in mind that a lot of stuff still works in 2013 but was deprecated and will probably be removed entirely in future releases. Here's a good list for starters:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/deprecated-features-in-sharepoint-2013-from-sharepoint-2010/